# How do I find the result that is not null?

Tags: sql, t-sql, cursor

I have a query which returns 2+ rows. In those results is a column which we can call **columnX** for now. Lets look at those example results:

**columnX

100

86

85

70

null

null**

I get 6 rows for example, some of them are null, some of them are not null. Now I want to go through those results and stop as soon as I find a row which is `<>` null. How can I do that?

---

Thing is, its always sorted that way. So if there are nulls, they are at the bottom. This can be a result:

**columnX

100

86

85

70

null

null**

and this as well:

**columnX

100

86

85

70**

So there can be nulls or not, in any case, I want to find the first not null rows, 70 in the above examples. I think the CTE is a nice start...but something is still missing. This is how I get those rows:

```
select columnx from mytable where someid = 12345
```

So the numbers in columnx all belong together (because someid). I really have to get the first not null row from that result. I cant just look for the first row that is not null from the whole columnx, I have to use a condition (where someid = 12345) before. The 70 is just an example, it can be 90 as well, so I cant get the minvalue from the results. The nulls are always at the bottom, the rest can be unsorted. This can be a result as well:

**columnX

100

23

80

78

null

null**

In that case I want the 78.

Comment: In what order do you want to go through them? Are they sorted descending, like in your example? If so, you could just do `select top 1 ... where columnX is not null`

Comment: Yes, they are ordered like that...so in my example I want to stop as soon as I find the 70.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to pull out an index alongside the column (using the `ROW_NUMBER` function).

You can then use a nested `select` to find the minimum null index, then select everything below that.

```
WITH cteMyTable AS
(
    SELECT RUW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (ColZ) as [Rank], ColumnX
    FROM MyTable
)

SELECT [Rank], ColumnX
FROM cteMyTable WHERE [Rank] < 
   (SELECT MIN([Rank]) FROM cteMyTable WHERE ColumnX IS NULL)
```

---

Edit following your further information, if you just want all rows where ColumnX is the minimum value, you can jsut do the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE ColumnX = (SELECT MIN(ColumnX) FROM MyTable)
```

Comment: Thanks, can u post me some sql please?

Comment: ORDER BY (ColZ) --> whats the ColZ?

Comment: ColZ is whatever you want your ordering to be by - maybe 'ColumnX' in your case...